# casting a pointer to an array to a structure in efficient C++11 way

Tags: c++, memory, casting, c++17

I have a big amount point cloud data that I read from a file into

```
char * memblock = new char [size];
```

where size is the size of data. Then I cast my data to float numbers

```
float * file_content = reinterpret_cast<float *>(memblock);
```

Now I would like to change the data from a pointer to an array and place it in a certain structure like `std::vector<PointXYZ>`.

```
vector.clear();
for (int i = 2; i < file_content_size; i+=3) {
 vector.push_back(
    PointXYZ(file_content[i-2], file_content[i-1], file_content[i] )
    );
}
```

But I feel there must be a better way than just looping through the whole data, considering that the size of the vector is more than 1e6.

Comment: How are you going to fill the vector *without* going through the original data?

Comment: Just a thought, is your point cloud data actually in binary format or is it a text (char) string?  If it is text, you can't just convert it to floats like that.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't know, map memory in a more efficient way while reading it? instead of loading to a `char *`, changing to `float *` and then copying...
@Marker it is indeed binary.

Comment: One million is not huge. Use reserve to speed it up.

Comment: *But I feel there must be a better way than just looping through the whole data* Instead of looking for efficient ways of translating the data, you could change your function/algorithm to use the raw data. Then, you won't have to pay for the time and memory cost of translating the data.

Comment: @ScottHunter, binary format certainly makes it easier and quicker.  Don't forget to make sure it is in the correct Endian order.  I'm surprised that std::vector or std::array don't have an "adopt" constructor that allows them to take ownership of an existing array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you alignment problems when you cast your `char*` raw data into a `float*`.

Generally you should arrange things so you cast other types to a `char*` because that is allowed to alias everything else and ensures you get correct alignment.

```
// create your array in the target type (float)
std::vector<float> file_content(size/sizeof(float));

// read the data in (cast to char* here)
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(file_content.data()), size);
```

I honestly don't think you can get away from copying all the data.

```
std::vector<PointXYZ> points;
points.reserve(file_content.size() / 3);

for(auto i = 0ULL; i < file_content.size(); i += 3)
    points.emplace_back(points[i], points[i + 1], points[i + 2])
```

Comment: Nope. Casting `char*` works the other way too. You can still get into trouble if you did a crazy thing like cast `char*` to `float*` and then had a different cast of `char*` to `int*`. The `float*` and `int*` would alias each other but the compiler wouldn't account for it. Bad things would happen.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector has a range constructor that you can use to copy the elements to the vector.

```
std::vector<PointXYZ> vec(memblock, memblock + size);
```

I believe this will be faster because you are not reallocating memory for every push_back, however you will still be doing a copy of all elements in memblock.